# summations with unusual notation,as interpreted?

Tags: algebra-precalculus, descriptive-statistics

I have seen here and in many places summations that do not follow a standard notation, I put some of them below:
For example how to interpret these.
Some bibliography with this type of notation? I can't find anything other than usual
[image]

Comment: I think that you need to provide the context for some of those in order for them to be interpreted, such as the ones involving variables under the summation that are not present anywhere else. But in general, they express constraints on which values of the variables represent terms to include in the summation. For example, the first one stipulates to sum over all nonnegative integers $r_1,\ldots,r_n$ such that the sum of those $n$ integers is $t$.

Comment: The $k\ge 0$ sum is for $k=0$ to $\infty$. Read Wikipedia [Divisor function](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Divisor_function) for the last sum.

Comment: Just to add more to the question, there is also cyclic summations and symmetric summations. Some words can be found at https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Cyclic_sum and https://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php/Symmetric_sum.

Answer (score 1):

The first does not appear to be a sum at all unless interpreted as on the right. The others also appear to be coded by people without a strong background in standard notation.
These are just educated guesses about what the coders intended.

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\large{r_1+r_2+\cdots+r_n = t,\space r_k \in\mathbb{N}}} 
\frac{t!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_n!}
\\ \longrightarrow\space
\sum_{\Large{t=r_1}}^{\Large{r_n,\space  r_k\in\mathbb{N}}} 
\frac{t!}{r_1!r_2!\cdots r_n!}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\large{1<t<k\le n}}
\ln\left(\ln\left(\sqrt[\huge{n}]{\frac{3n-2k}{3n+2k}}\right)\right) 
\\\longrightarrow\space 
\sum_{\large{k>t>1}}^{\Large{n}}
\ln\left(\ln\left(\sqrt[\huge{n}]{\frac{3n-2k}{3n+2k}}\right)\right) 
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\large{k\ge0} }
(tk)^{k-1}\frac{z^k}{k!}
\quad\longrightarrow\quad 
\sum_{\large{k=0} }^{\Large{\infty}}
(tk)^{k-1}\frac{z^k}{k!}
\end{align*}

\begin{align*}
\sum_{\large{d|n}} g(d)
\quad\longrightarrow\quad 
\sum_{\large{\frac{n}{d}=1}}^{\Large{\infty}, 
\space \frac{n}{d}\in\mathbb{N}}
\space 
g(d) 
\end{align*}

Comment: The first one is the sum of the multinomial coefficients for $(x_1+\ldots+x_n)^t$, and is therefore equal to $n^t$. See the multinomial theorem.